# SVMLight: "Version of model-file does not match version of svm_classify!"

Tags: svmlight

I've got the most current version of SVMLight installed (V6.02). I can create a model with no trouble using svm_learn, but when I go to classify with svm_classify, I get the following:

```
Reading model...Version of model-file does not match version of svm_classify!: Undefined error: 0
```

This is somewhat frustrating to me, as both of these were working a couple weeks ago. I've got a fresh install working here, and both svm_learn and svm_classify show V6.02 as the working version.

Any thoughts? I'm entirely stumped.

Comment: Update: there appears to be a bug in svm_common.c at line 600, to wit...  

`fscanf(modelfl,"SVM-light Version %s\n",version_buffer);`

This line fails to properly parse its companion line in the model file, i.e., `SVM-light Version V6.02`

I'm not terribly adept at C, so I'll give fixing this my best shot.